# Cannot include <vector>

Tags: c++, gcc, vector

I am using gcc under OS X and I get an error

```
fatal error: 'vector' file not found
```

when trying to include the vector implementation. Other includes like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

are working. Where is the vector file located?

Comment: Are you coding C or C++? `stdio.h` and `stdlib.h` are C includes while `vector` is C++.

Comment: Did you try using `g++` rather than `gcc` ?

Comment: You can not use vector in c.

Comment: @denis You can use vector in c++, but not in c

Comment: Sorry that was a typo I corrected that.Header he/she added, clearly indicates it is a C file and hence can not use vector.

Comment: Why post the working code and not the code that doesn't work? We need to see the code that *doesn't work*. We know what working code looks like.

Answer (score 7):

`vector` is not part of C. You must use C++.

Try compiling with `g++` rather than `gcc`

Comment: Thank you! I honestly didn't know, that vector is a C++ feature. It works now! Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2):

The `vector` C++ header enables the use of vector template  class.

Include :

```
#include<vector>
```

and compile the program using g++.

Comment: 'vector' file not found, 'vector' file not found, 'vector' file not found, 'vector' file not found, 'vector' file not found, 'vector' file not found, 'vector' file not found, 'vector' file not found, 'vector' file not found, 'vector' file not found, 'vector' file not found, 'vector' file not found, 'vector' file not found, 'vector' file not found, 'vector' file not found,

Answer (score 0):

Vector file you can add in c++ only, C doesn't support the vector property.

Comment: sorry its typo vector templates .